# Is it possible to show and hide forms fields on Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have been playing with the bootstrap modal to show a form. All is ok for fixed fields, but im trying to show div depending of the value of a previous field and reading several examples of toggle visibility on divs using .show .hide work ok out of the modal box, but in the modal all is shown . I am new with bootstrap, sorry if my question is out of place, any lights will be appreciated. This is the form:

```
<div id="createEventModal" class="modal hide">

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3>Crear Pauta</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="PautasForm" class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputTitle">Title:</label>
            <div class="controls space">
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                <input type="hidden" id="apptStartTime"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="apptEndTime"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="apptAllDay"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="apptResource"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="apptUser"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="apptEdit"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="apptID"/>
            </div>

            <div id="seller">
                <label class="control-label" for="SelIng">Seller</label>

                <div class="controls space">
                    <select id="ing" name="ing">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <?php
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ing)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $row['id_ing'] . "'>" . $row['nombre_ing'] . "</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="task">
                <label class="control-label" for="SelTask">Task</label>

                <div class="controls space">
                    <select id="task" name="task">
                        <option value="0">Select task</option>
                        <option value="1">Customer Service</option>
                        <option value="2">Inventory</option>
                        <option value="3">Staff Management</option>                            
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="loc">
                <label class="control-label" for="SelLoc">Manager</label>

                <div class="controls space">
                    <select id="manager" name="manager">
                        <option value="">Select Manager</option>
                        <?php
                        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($loc)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $row2['loc_id'] . "'>" . $row2['nombre_completo'] . "</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="when">When:</label>
            <div class="controls controls-row" id="when" style="margin-top:5px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton">Guardar</button>
</div>
```

And this is the script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function () {

toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
        //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of our underAge field changes
        $("#task").change(function () {
            toggleFields();
        });

    });

    function toggleFields() {
        if ($("#task").val() == 1) {
            $("#loc").show();
        } else {
            $("#loc").hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide an example of what you created so far ?

Comment: ok, sorry updating my question

Answer (score 1):

Without testing or seeing what you're doing in action, my theory is:

Everything is already hidden when your toggle function is getting called so hiding elements within it does nothing. Either that or showing the modal overrides hiding of inner elements.

Try calling the toggle when your modal is getting shown instead.

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  toggleFields();
});
```

Comment: The problem i had was that i was calling the function later in my script section, and some fields was generated dynamicly. Thanks